# Function accepting generic parameters

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I have a subclass of `NSManagedObject`. I'm using a protocol to create a "wrapper" class. In my controller the data can be either: `Items` or `Item1`. To be able to use my `function` I'll have to add the protocol `ItemInfo` to `Items` but that means I'll have to add

```
var items: Items { return self }
```

in `Items`, which seems a bit redundant. I've tried creating a base class but that didn't work.

---

### Question:

Is there a better way to let my function accept both `Items` and `Item1` as parameter like using generics?

---

`NSManagedObject`:

```
class Items: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var code: String
}
```

---

`Protocol`:

```
protocol ItemInfo {
    var item: Items { get }
}

extension ItemInfo {

    var name : String { return item.name }
    var code : String { return item.code }
}
```

`Wrapper`:

```
class Item1: ItemInfo {
    let item: Items

    init(item: Items) { self.item = item }
}
```

---

`function`:

```
func handleItem(item: ItemInfo) {
    print(item.name)
    print(item.code)
}
```

---

I could use:

```
func handleItem<T>(item: T) {
    if let a = item as? Items {
        print(a.name)
        print(a.code)
    }

    if let a = item as? ItemInfo {
        print(a.name)
        print(a.code)
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem the right way ...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve (function accepting two kind of items), I would use protocol as type accepted by function, refer the code below

```
class Items: NSManagedObject, ItemInfo {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var code: String
}

class Item1: NSManagedObject, ItemInfo {

    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var code: String
}

protocol ItemInfo {
    var name: String {get set}
    var code: String {get set}
}
```

and function would look like this

```
func handle(item: ItemInfo) {
    print(item.code)
    print(item.name)
}
```

Comment: `Item1` (or protocol `ItemInfo`) is just merely a "wrapper" of `Items` though. Also `Items` is actually a lot more complicated. I just simplified it here so it's more readable.